# Does order of operators matter when using compound assignment in Java? (+= vs =+)

Tags: java, operators, addition

I have this test code and I am trying to check if `sum =+ value` is equal to `sum = sum + value`. In Java, is this acceptable? It compiles and runs on my machine.

```
public class sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int value = 5;

        sum =+ value;
        System.out.println(sum);

        sum = 0;
        sum = sum + value;

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the initial value of `sum` to anything other than ` 0 ` for example `3` , and then you can see the difference .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it matters.

There is no `=+` operator. It's, in fact, two operators - `=` (assignment), followed by `+` (unary plus). 
`sum =+ value` could be written as `sum = (+value)`, which just evaluates to `sum = value`.

On the other hand `+=` is a proper operator using for addition `sum += value` means `sum = sum + value`.